# What are the little grey things in RAM modules?

Tags: memory, hardware-rec

I was upgrading my laptop's RAM and, after removing a module, one of the little grey things (circled in red in the image below) came off.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what this is?

And if it is dangerous, as in, should I replace the module that has this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is most likely a capacitor (edited - previously posited it was a resistor or diode).

While not **dangerous** in the traditional sense, it is necessary for the proper and consistent functionality of the RAM module.  So **YES** you should consider this module busted and replace it.  A decoupling capacitor acts as a noise filter that will help clean signals on the module, without it then signal noise could cause bits to flip improperly/unexpectedly.  While that won't fry your PC, it could cause "strangeness" in your programs or OS, from hiccups in operation to bad data saves or full system crashes.  If the PC isn't in an electrically noisy environment, you may not even notice a difference.  That said, I'd still replace as soon as I could.

As a general rule when bits are removed from (or fall off of) an electrical circuit, it fundamentally changes the properties of the circuit making it so that it won't operate as intended (if at all).  Which is a polite way of saying "broken".

Comment: Can I keep using this module until I get the new one, or should I remove it immediately?

Comment: If you put it in the computer, and the computer is actually working you could try to keep using it.  I would strongly suggest you run a full memtest86 for a couple passes before you trusted it with any actual data.  If is broken in a way that makes it seem functional but corrupts your data then you stored data on your drives would become corrupt as you modified them.  tl;dr best to just not used it, second best is to only use it after it has passed memory tests.

Comment: @Zoredache I ran a memtest and it passed, that's why I'm using it. I'll get the new module by wednesday, at worst. However, I'd like to keep using this one until then. But, if it fails memtests, I'll remove it immediately.

Comment: *"That is either a resistor or diode"* -- It's far more likely to be a capacitor than a diode.  And based on the brown body color, there's 99% chance that it is a capacitor.

Comment: @sawdust does that mean that the module can damage the computer?

Comment: @m-oliv -- No.  The cap's function is most likely as a decoupling capacitor.  So that could cause memory errors, rather than damage to the mobo.  Have you tried to get a replacement under warranty?

Comment: @sawdust this is the main memory module that came with the computer, some 5 or 6 years ago. The computer's warranty is gone, and I assume this part's warranty is gone too. So, I'm going to buy another memory module to replace this one.

Comment: @m-oliv -- If you can find someone who can do (surface-mount) soldering, then the module could be repaired.

Comment: @sawdust I'd try that, but unfortunately I lost the tiny part that came off... So I guess my computer's getting a full RAM upgrade. :(

Comment: sawdust Good catch. On my original screen I thought I saw stripes hence my initial conclusion.  On this better monitor I'd have to agree they are decoupling caps.  m-oliv If these are decoupling capacitors, then they won't cause immediate faults and everything will work *until* noise is introduced into the system (the cap is a noise suppressor).  If noise gets on the lines you may have bits incorrectly flipped resulting in unstable data on RAM (depending on your use case that could be anything from a nuisance to catastrophe, that's up to you to decide)

Answer (score 2):

Those are almost definitely capacitors. I know because we use them extensively in electronics.

The design of the board and position of the capacitors makes be strongly believe that they are simply decoupling capacitors, we put them across the power line and ground on a microchip like this as a filter to get rid of any noise on the chip power supply.

It having been knocked off will not damage your computer unless it tore a bit of track so that the pads are now shorted together. Make sure that the pads are clear. Other than that the worst that would happen is the memory module might "misbehave" at times, though it would be difficult to say how problems might manifest.

The capacitor is essentially an open circuit to DC voltages, but effectively connects high frequency noise to ground. There are generally a few placed close together near any lines that need protection, and loosing one probably won't actually affect the memory module much, if at all, but it *might*.

In case you care, the little black 8 pin packages at the bottom are 4-way resistor packs, almost certainly terminating the data lines going to the chips.